# Function like save excursion for restoring buffers?

Tags: buffers

When I want to do something in another buffer and then restore the original, I currently do this:

```el
(let ((this-buffer (current-buffer)))
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))
  (insert "I was here!")
  (switch-to-buffer this-buffer))
```

Is there a less verbose way to this, something like:

```el
(save-buffer-and-switch (other-buffer)
  (insert "I was here!"))
```

Comment: `switch-to-buffer` is just plain wrong here: it changes which buffer is *displayed* in the currently selected window, whereas you just want to change the currently selected buffer.  IOW instead of `switch-to-buffer` you would want `set-buffer`.  See `C-h f switch-to-buffer RET`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `with-current-buffer`:

```el
(with-current-buffer (other-buffer)
  (insert "I was here!"))
```

There is also `save-current-buffer`, which is a simpler mechanism used to implement the `with-current-buffer` macro:

```el
(save-current-buffer
  (set-buffer (other-buffer))
  (insert "I was here!"))
```

The combination of `save-current-buffer` and `set-buffer` mostly seems to show up in older code.  Most of the time, `with-current-buffer` is clearer, IMO.

Comment: Wow, I even searched for `with-buffer` in `helm-apropos`, but missed it (HA lists all commands before functions, so it was far down in the list).

Comment: @24HrRevengeTherapist You can use `C-o` to switch sources in helm. You can also use `C-h v` look up function/macro's docstring, don't forget to turn on `helm-mode` since it provides a very handy persistent-action.

Comment: @xuchunyang Did you mean `C-h f` (`describe-function`)?  `C-h v` is bound to `describe-variable` in my Emacs.  But maybe this is different under Helm, I don't know.

Comment: @JonO. Yes, it's a typo, I meant `C-h f`.